# Firebase auth redirect to Google sign in page to Vue Router

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, vue-router, google-account

I'm using VueJS with Vue Router. Since changing the Firebase **auth** domain from the default **example.firebaseapp.com** to **example.com** the redirect that lets users authenticate with their Google account isn't working anymore. The redirect is stuck at `https://example.com/__/auth/handler?apiKey=X&appName=X&authType=signInViaRedirect&providerId=google.com`

```
firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "123456789",
  authDomain: "example.com",
  databaseURL: "https://example.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "example",
  storageBucket: "example.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "123456789"
});
```

I tried removing my htaccess and adding the redirect url `/__/auth/` as a route path.

**router.js:**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import router from "vue-router";

import Signup from "./components/User/Signup";
import AuthGuard from "./auth-guard";
import NotFound from "./components/User/NotFound";

Vue.use(router);

export default new router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "Home",
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: "/signup",
      name: "Signup",
      component: Signup
    },
    { path: "*", name: "NotFound", component: NotFound }
  ],
  mode: "history"
});
```

**auth-guard.js**

```
import store from "./store";

export default (to, from, next) => {
  if (store.getters.user) {
    next();
  } else {
    next("/signup");
  }
};
```

How to make the redirect work?